# Get sum of changes which occur over time for different sets of values

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a table with measurements acquired over time. There is one parameter measured. Measured values come from meters identified by IP address and an ID. ID is unique for given IP so a meter is uniquely identified by IP-ID pair. I'd like to know the sum of changes of measured value from all meters over given period of time.

The columns in table are like this:

```
val, meter_ip, meter_id, time_stamp
```

Now I'm calculating the change for one given meter using two queries:

```
SELECT val
FROM measurements
WHERE meter_ip=@ip AND meter_id=@id AND
      time_stamp > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
ORDER BY time_stamp ASC
LIMIT 1
```

and

```
SELECT val
FROM measurements
WHERE meter_ip=@ip AND meter_id=@id AND
      time_stamp > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
ORDER BY time_stamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

and then I'm subtracting obtained values.
I'm sure this can be done in one SQL query but I don't know how to do it. And first of all I'm looking for solution of main problem which is summing up differences for all meters. I suppose I need some grouping by IP and ID.

Comment: I think it's OK. I want to narrow down to records not older than one day (or month or year, a day is just an example). Actually as I want to find the newest record I can omit this condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is guaranteed that you have a unique time_stamp per each pair you can use the MIN() and MAX() for that, like this:

```
SELECT a.meter_ip, a.meter_id,
a.val, b.val, b.val - a.val as diff
FROM (select meter_ip, meter_id, 
      min(time_stamp) as min_time_stamp,
      max(time_stamp) as max_time_stamp
      FROM measurements
      WHERE time_stamp > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
      GROUP BY meter_ip, meter_id) c
INNER JOIN measurements a ON a.meter_ip = c.meter_ip and 
      a.meter_id = c.meter_id AND a.time_stamp = c.min_time_stamp
INNER JOIN measurements b ON b.meter_ip = c.meter_ip and 
      b.meter_id = c.meter_id AND b.time_stamp = c.max_time_stamp
```

However, if there could be duplicate time_stamp values per each meter_ip, meter_id pairs then this solution will not work for you

Comment: Values from different meters are stored independently but with the same frequency (once per minute). Therefore there are no duplicate time_stamp values as the minimum difference for time_stamp values for given IP-ID pair is one minute. Thank you very much!